# How do I make a background color extend into my fractional columns without affecting my center columns?

Tags: css, html, sass, grid-layout

I am setting up a template for for demos on how to use a certain portion of a program. I have set up the pages in an 8-column grid layout with an empty 1fr column on either side for padding. The problem I am running into is putting a background color behind the content to offset the content as the user scrolls down the page. I'm having trouble coming up with a solution that spans the background color across the entire viewport width, while keeping the content within the 8 grids.

I have tried adding another class to the  tag named "bg". I did this to span the bg color across the entire viewport, but then it forces the content outside of the center 8 grids which I don't want the content to escape from. I've also tried giving .bg a width of 100vw, but it then overrides the content grid again.

Html

```
<div class="container">
<section class="cont2 bg">
        <img src="img/perf-2.png" alt="" class="cont2__img">
        <div class="cont2__content">
            <p class="cont2__content--p-1">
                For this example, we are looking at the effects of investing $10,000 in JNJ with a start date of December 1998, and how today that money would be worth about $40,566. 
            </p>
            <p class="cont2__content--p-2">
                These performance results located at the bottom you can find the average dividend growth rate for the timeframe selected with the compounded annual growth rate, the total amount of dividends paid, and the growth breakdown of the stock you are looking at.  
            </p>
            <p class="cont2__content--p-3">
                This is then in comparison to investing in the S&P 500 over the same timeframe.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS (sass)

```
// Container Grid layout
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20vh repeat(4, min-content); // I have 4 content sections for the entire project, so that's why there is repeat 4
    grid-template-columns:  [full-start] minmax(6rem, 1fr) [center-start] 
repeat(8, [col-start] minmax(min-content, 20rem) [col-end]) [center-end] 
minmax(6rem, 1fr) [full-end];
}

// Content Layout
.cont2 {
grid-column: center-start / center-end;
margin: 10rem 0;
padding: 5rem;

grid-row: 3 / 4;

display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr)); //responsive layout
grid-gap: 4rem;

&__content {
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    &--p-2 {
        margin-top: 3rem;
        margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
}

&__img {
    width: 100%;
}
}


.bg {
//width: 100vw;
//grid-column: full-start / full-end;
background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);

//I've tried more than the commented out lines, but I've been trying it for a little bit tonight and forgot - sorry
}
```

I want the background color of .bg to bleed across the entire page, while keeping the integrity of the content within the 8 center columns.

Thanks in advance and let me know if I need to provide anymore info.

Comment: Hi, would be great if u could provide fiddle for that. Your question is not clear for me, maybe u could provide as simple example as possible. Specially that code you provided is missing jpegs and no columns are visible when i try to run it.

Comment: @Andreew4x4 Sorry of I wasn't clear. Here is a codepen with the same layout of code. I want the grey background to spread across the entire background and not just the center 8 columns. https://codepen.io/coltcarnevale/pen/gZepaP?editors=1100

Comment: is there any reason you can't just put the background-color on `.container` ?

Comment: @philr Yes because that would cover the entire container (including cont and cont2). Look at the codepen I posted in the comment above. I need it to cover only .cont, but across the entire viewport and not .cont2 at all.